# Is it "javax" illegal(reserved) package name or not?

Tags: java, package, naming

I have found information that java.* and javax.* are illegal(reserved) package names(in the book "OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Study Guide"). When I try create package "java" and run class from it, I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
```

but when I run class from "javax" package I receive no errors. On docs.oracle.com I've found only information:

```
Packages in the Java language itself begin with java. or javax.
```

so... is it "javax" illegal name or not? Maybe it's illegal only on Java EE, or older versions of Java?(I've tried it on JDK 1.6.0_43 and 1.7.0_25)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this thread already. It gives good information about javax package, but it doesn't say is it legal name for package or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javax.` is used for extensions (possibly within the JRE), so sure it is possible to define classes within those packages. IIRC, this can be disabled in untrusted contexts by adding `javax.` to the `package.definition` security property (not checked).

`java.` is special because `ClassLoader` prevents non-bootstrap class loader in those packages as an anti-Microsoft measure.

Comment: I don't think Java is just special because of the classloader; it contains the official baseline API of Java. Do you have any references for this answer?

Comment: @owlstead `java/lang/ClassLoader.java`. Specifically `preDefineClass` method.

Comment: @SathOkh Yes, otherwise it would not be possible to implement specific [JSR's](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/all). It is of course very unwise to put any *other* libraries (than the ones specified in a JSR) or applications in the `javax` namespace. The fact that it does not directly flag a compiler error does not mean that you should use it.