# Java Email with Commons Mail

Tags: java, email

I'm trying to send a email with commons api, but, i goting error!

This is an example of Commons guide, but, i cant send here..

```
public class Emailsss {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)  throws EmailException, MalformedURLException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // Create the email message
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "mypw"));
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setFrom("username");
    email.setSubject("TestMail");
    email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
    email.addTo("to");

      URL url = new URL("http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif");
      String cid = email.embed(url, "Apache logo");
      email.setHtmlMsg("<html>The apache logo - <img src=\"cid:"+cid+"\"></html>");
      email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");

      // send the email
      email.send();
    } 
  }
```

And here's my error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail.build(HtmlEmail.java:581)
at org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail.buildMimeMessage(HtmlEmail.java:519)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1436)
at emailsss.Emailsss.main(Emailsss.java:46)
 Java Result: 1
```

Comment: How do you build it? What other jars are part of the classpath?

Comment: i got mail.jar, activation.jar, commons.jar... only @MichaelT

Comment: looks like you are missing a jar file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar

Answer (score 2):

You likely need the javax mail package that can be found at (for example) http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar

---

If you are building with maven itself (you didn't say you are, but using a dependancy manager is a good thing and probably would have solved your issue...)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

If you note the maven dependancies for [org.apache.commons](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email/1.1) you will see:

This artifact depends on ...

- javax.mail

And if you had used maven, the [pom file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-email/1.1/commons-email-1.1.pom) for org.apache.commons has javax.mail as the first depenancy.

All that said, download that link for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar include it in your class path and you should be good.

---

While on the subject, you may wish to read  [javax vs java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package)
which answers the question of why javax is different and separate from the java packages.