# Can not find UserTransaction interface in javax.transaction package

Tags: java

Why i can not import `javax.transaction.UserTransaction`? In official doc is indicated that there is
UserTransaction interface inside the  `javax.transaction` package, however i cannot import it because in  fact it does not exist. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: It does exist and that's a fact. If you insist on it not existing, there's no way we can help you. It was even back in the days of Java 1.4 http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html EDIT: You do realize that it belongs to Java EE and not Java SE, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class is not found in the default JRE/JDK library (here's a [discussion about java vs javax package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package)).

You need to add it in your classpath. [Here are some jars that are including it](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html).