# Hierarchy of Java Packages

Tags: java, package

I was trying to understand the general hierarhcy of Java packages.
If you consult this [Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-tree.html), it seems that there are 3 main packages:
java, javax and org.
All packages, in Java platform 7, start with one of these three.
Are these ones part of a bigger package?
I'd love to see a complete tree, but the one offered by Oracle is very confusing, because it's too detailed.

Another thing I did not undestand is why  packages like "java.awt" and "java.awt.color", or "java.lang" and "java.lang.annotation", are put by Oracle on the same level.
I did read online that if you import a "parent-package", you don't import any classes form the "child-packages", and that makes sense. However, it's hard to think that there isn't a relation between java.awt and java.awt.color; It seems intuitive that the least is contained in the fromer.
So, given my current understanding, I would draw a tree that look like this:
[image]

Comment: "However, it's hard to think that there isn't a relation between java.lang and java.lang.color" - there really isn't as far as the language is concerned. The only hierarchy is imposed by human understanding.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't understand what you  are trying to suggest me :(

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti The relation is within the intend, not within the language. The developers of `java.awt` needed a representation for colors, so they wrote a package `colors` for awt. Thus, they put `color` as sub-package it in `java.awt`.

Comment: I'm trying to say that whether it's hard to think it or not, there really *isn't* a relationship between different packages, as far as the language is concerned.

Comment: @Turing85: I can't edit the comment now - but everything apart from the name still applies :)

Comment: Hard to say, but I think, it was because `java.awt.color` was primary used for `awt` - first java graphics, which came. After some time it was "renewed" by `javax.swing` - notice there is no colors in swing anymore :) So i guess it is from historical reasons.

Comment: Read related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package. Also see the Java9 module dependency structure as it is related to jdk packages: https://dzone.com/articles/java-9-modularity-jigsaw

Comment: Packages technically have no hierarchy, each packages is a thing on its own (it is not 'nested' in a parent package). So there is no package `java`, and for example `java.util.concurrent` is not a part of package `java.util`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/package-index.html    It looks like sometimes it's included

Comment: That is just that sites interpretation, it is not how it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no "bigger" package. The structure evolved over time, with different ideas and marketing influencing the naming.

You do not import packages in java, just classes. So before Java9, it does not really matter much even in which package a class resides except for the package-protected visibility scope (which is not used that much), and the lack of need to import classes from the same package.

Often classes from a subpackage are used by classes in a parent package, but not the other way round. But there is no strict rule about this.