# Class javax.activation.DataSource not found

Tags: java, selenium

The Java class was not found when the application was run on a test laptop.  The following exception was thrown:
[image: screenshot of the exception]

The test is run from an executable JAR file that was created in Eclipse on the development laptop.  As I understand, the executable JAR should contain all support libraries.

When I run the executable JAR from the development laptop, I don't encounter the exception.  It is encountered on the test system only.  That's what is difficult to understand.

Secondly, I downloaded and added reference to activation-1.1.1.jar in the build path - but it did not help.  The same exception is thrown.

So, I am scratching my head and looking for experts' help :)

Thanks.

Comment: This "As I understand, the executable JAR should contain all support libraries." is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Please do not include images of text in a question.  Text should be present in a question as a text block.

Comment: Your class path is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - All libraries are in the same folder and that's how they are referred to in Eclipse (project > Build Path).  So, I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @SiKing - I relied on Eclipse to include all libraries when I checked the option for "Package required libraries into generated JAR" for library handling. An option to selectively add libraries is not presented in the export process.

Comment: You need to provide a class path at runtime too or use the one inside the jar with `-jar`

Comment: What vendor/version of Java do you have on the build machine and on the runtime machine? Not a duplicate, but have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/q/727844/3124333

Comment: @SiKing - I am using Open JDK 8

Comment: Do you understand what the classpath is and how it works?    Including the fact that _nothing_ automatically saves your classpath at build time for later?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen:   Yes, and yes.   On the command to run the executable jar, the classpath is set to include the correct path to the library in question.